# Pandas: Speed up minimum value extraction

Tags: python, performance, sorting, pandas

I have a huge data frame (~10,000,000 lines) that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col1 = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
col2 = ['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
col3 = [14, 36, 5, 12, 96]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([col1, col2, col3]),
                  columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df['col3'] = df['col3'].astype(int)


  col1 col2  col3
0    A    B    14
1    C    A    36
2    D    B     5
3    D    C    12
4    D    A    96
```

I want to find the minimum value associated to each unique term (A, B, C, D):

```
A B 14
D B 5
C D 12
D B 5
```

I tried the following but it's too slow:

```
for i in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
   dm = df.loc[(df['col1'] == i) | (df['col2'] == i)]
   print dm.ix[dm['col3'].idxmin()]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use melt to go to the long form and use groupby.min:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['col3']).groupby('value')['col3'].min()
Out: 
value
A    14
B     5
C    12
D     5
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @dcirillo it's best to accept an answer (click the checkmark) if you are happy with it in order to reward the answerer and signal that the question has been satisfactorily answered

Comment: @dcirillo Please exept this answer because you said that it satissfied your requests. Thank you comments are not allowed, only accepting is. I deleted your thank you comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can locate the smallest value for each of the two columns and then take the minimum:

```
pd.concat([df.groupby('col1').min(), df.groupby('col2').min()], axis=1)\
         .min(axis=1).astype(int)
#A    14
#B     5
#C    12
#D     5
```

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat similar in approach to @DYZ's answer although much faster in my testing.  I'm happy to delete it if it is considered too derivative to be posted as a separate answer.

```
df1 = df.groupby('col1')['col3'].min()
df2 = df.groupby('col2')['col3'].min()
df1.append(df2).groupby(level=0).min()

A    14
B     5
C    12
D     5
```

I tested by simply expanding the test data to 10,240 rows.  In that case it's much faster than the other proposed solutions but a little slower (10%) than @ayhan's answer, but perhaps with other data it might be significantly faster or slower in comparison.